Stripe, want to add data in metadata for invoice.payment_succeeded webhook
I am trying to integrate a subscription based model and followed the stripe docs for the code Subscription using react and Node.
subscription checkoutSession
export const createCheckoutSessionForSubscription = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body, 'req.body in stripe subscription');

  const prices = await Stripe.prices.list({
    lookup_keys: [req.body.lookup_key],
    expand: ['data.product'],
  });
 
  // console.log(prices, 'prices in stripe');

  const session = await Stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    metadata:{
      userId:req.body.userId,
    },
    billing_address_collection: 'auto',
    line_items: [
      {
        price: prices.data[0].id,
        // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
        quantity: 1,

      },
      
    ],
    mode: 'subscription',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/productDisplay/?success=true&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?canceled=true`,
  });

  
  // console.log('session in stripe subscription',session);
  
  res.redirect(303, session.url);

}

Using webhook I have two events
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), async (request, response) => {
  const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  try {
    event = Stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    return;
  }

    // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
case 'checkout.session.completed':
{logic}
break;

 case 'invoice.payment_succeeded':
{logic}
breakl
}


When I check the event logs, my invoice.payment_succeeded metadata is empty but checkout.session.completed has metadata with userId in it.
How can I add metadata to the other event?

The Checkout Session object is its own object with its own metadata property.
If you want your Invoices to have their own metadata, you need to use invoice_creation.invoice_data.metadata (API reference here) when creating the Checkout Session. This will ensure that the Invoices created by your Checkout Sessions get metadata.
